# We have detected that your app contains the Request Legacy External Storage tag in the manifest file for one or more app or APK packages

Tags: request, storage, external, google-play-console

We have detected that your app contains the Request Legacy External Storage tag in the manifest file for one or more app or APK packages.

Developers who have apps on devices running Android OS 11 or later should use the Subsidiary Storage feature to give users better control over accessing the storage space available on their device. To launch your app on Android OS 11 or later after May 5, you need to perform one of the following steps:

Update your app to use privacy best practices such as Storage Access Framework or Media Store API
Update your app to announce the permission to access all files (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) in the manifest file, and to complete the statement of access permission to all files in the Play Console as of May 5
Completely remove the permission to access all files from your app
For apps targeting Android 11, the request Legacy External Storage tag will be ignored. You have to use the access permission to all files to retain access to external storage space.

Applications that require access to all files without permission to use will be removed from Google Play, and you will not be able to publish updates.

I want someone to help me

Answer (score 3):

if your targetSdk is not 30 you can keep using that flag
`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`
And you don' t have to do anything.
But developers should do targetSdk = 30  in November.
I share answer which came from google:

"you can continue to use requestLegacyExternalStorage after May 5th since you are not targeting Android 11. You do not need to do anything before May 5th."

In our application targetSdk = 29 and we use requestLegacyExternalStorage. If you are in the same condition, you don' t have to do anything for now.

If in your application targetSDK = 30 you have two option:
if your application is need access all files in device, use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.  But you should submit a form for this permission.

Or you can use Storage access framework or the MediaStore API to handle your file access features.

Comment: How did you get this answer? By email? Where did Google share this answer?

Comment: Yes, by email. 

But only this part is from email "you can continue to use requestLegacyExternalStorage after May 5th since you are not targeting Android 11. You do not need to do anything before May 5th". 

Other parts are which is my understand from docs.

Comment: what should we do if we request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at runtime?(removing from Manifest)Is it against Google Play Policies?